# Waterproof charging of LiPo

Tags: soldering, charging, lipo, waterproof

I found this thread: [Wireless charging Lipo batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/517172/wireless-charging-lipo-batteries?newreg=ea3a155de3c247bd81b2569470f00814)

My problem is slightly different. I have 2s Lipo that I need to charge (way less than 1c, overnight is fine.) The problem is that the casing needs to be watertight (saltwater/freshwater no pressure.) Mainly it should not get in water but it happened once and I fried all my electronics, so the next version I would like to have watertight, but I would like it to be simple to charge and setup. This yields me with 3 options as I see:

1. 3D print a hatch to access the balance coord. Needs bolts and gaskets and also unsure how well it will seal.
2. Waterproof connector, there is no waterproof connector as far as I know that goes to balance charge lead, i.e. I need to solder my custom cable for each unit. Also how well does connector tolerate seawater?
3. Wireless charging, might be bulky also struggling with finding one that directly connects to 2s balance lead.

Any ideas how to solve this issue with charging?

It is a 2s 1000mah battery with JST connector.

Comment: Wireless charging just supplies power to the circuitry : so, just seal all the charging circuit including balancing and protection in the enclosure with the battery.

Comment: yes was the plan, but i can not find 2s version..

Comment: @skatun a 2S charge controller seems like a fairly standard device. You may need to combine a separate wireless power transfer receiver with the charge controller.

Comment: its seems like everything is for 1s, so maybe option 2 is better

Comment: @skatun A [quick search](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/pmic-battery-chargers/781?s=N4IgjCBcoMwGxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDa4ATGDBQoTAJwAcADAgLqEAOALlCAGUeAJwCWAOwDmIAL6EALGAqIQKSBhwFiZEPLhMKFAKwh6cIzBbLOIXvyFipswgFpl0VVBEBXLSUjkJuwyIUA) shows plenty of 2s charge controllers that you can put on the inside of the waterproof barrier, connected to the wireless power receiver (and perhaps a boost regulator if needed)

Comment: How deep in water are we talking, because the pressures mount up pretty quickly. What is the maximum depth?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD not deep at all, 10cm...... nanofarad i was looking for a plug and play solution. If I first need to solder then i guess a waterproof plug might work just as well(Gx12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that would not require soldering is to get a cable gland, JST extension cord, and some protective caps(these are not 100% watertight though)

@microservicesONDD soultion this would also leave the JST balance plug exposed, but here no soldering is needed.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On option 2, if you're willing to pay for military grade connectors then once connected they will handle pretty much everything you're likely to meet.  Rain, salt spray, fog or dust storms.

connecting them up in the middle of a storm may not be so good, though.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is working with the cable you've got, but cutting it and splicing it back together using waterproof entry lines. Here's the basic idea:

Use a waterproof food storage container, but position it upside-down, because that is usually a good first step to being waterproof:

[image]

Then we're going to do this:

[image]

You use a waterproof food storage container turned upside-down, and drill small holes in the lid, one for each wire coming through.  We are going to use magnet wire, as there is no space for water to enter. [Here is my pick of magnet wire, a nice red color, 24 AWG, (Enameled Copper Wire, Enameled Magnet Winding Wire)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NBM0MB5) is decent thickness, and **NO** air gaps where water will work its wily way in with.

[image]

Normal wire has a PVC jacket that has space inside that nobody thinks about when working with water, especially with stranded wire having plenty of space and surface area for a strong wicking situation. So, we're using magnet wire, a separate magnet wire penetrating the container-top for each wire in the cable, including a shield, if there is one. The magnet wire should come all the way out of the salt-water, so it has to be long enough, otherwise you will have problems on the outside cable,  with salt-water wicking into it through capillary action.

For this side view, you can see that I've bent the wire over where it goes through the top.  That's to prevent it from wiggling due to stresses from moving or vibrating the wires, and the gray rounded rectangle represents aquarium sealant that you use to make sure that water stays out. It is hollow in the diagram, but really, it's completely filled with sealant in real life.

[image]

You'll have to repeat this, four times, once for each of the wires coming through. (I say four times because I'm assuming 4 for the sake of this discussion, but you would use 10 wires if that's how many your cable had -- the rule is that all wires have to come through.)

Finally, join the original cables to the magnet wires coming through, and remember to keep them straight because they're the same color. Use your multimeter to add labels on each end of each magnet-wire, labels that uniquely identify them, and names are better than numbers, like "red", "blue", "green" representing what they are attaching to.  And after I've added the labels, I verify again. That adage for carpentry, "measure twice, cut once", I consider a principle for successfully getting things like this done without trajedy -- double and triple check every step, especially if it's tricky!

If you use this method, hopefully it will work and you won't have to try going the wireless route.